# USB Thethering and 3G wireless routers

Tags: wireless-networking, router, 3g, tethering

Is it possible to connect tethered android phone to USB socket of a 3G wifi router to access internet in place of regular USB dongle? If yes,how?

Comment: Are you asking if its possible to use your phone as a wireless adapter to connected to a 802.11 access point?

Comment: Sounds like he's asking if instead of buying a 3G dongle if he can plug his phone in and turn on USB tethering... I would say "probably not" - when you tether your phone via USB the computer installs a virtual network adapter and I'll guess that the drivers are quite different to those on USB dongles of the same nature...

Answer (score 0):

I've been researching this to use my phone as a hotspot so that my home network can utilise the internet connection.

The most common solution to date is enable the hotspot feature of your phone and connect (tether) it to the router.

There are at least 2 router manufacturers I've come across that support this feature.

Billion 7800 series (see link below)
http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/2219953

Selected ASUS ADSL routers (see link below)
http://event.asus.com/2013/nw/mobile_tethering_support/

There is a lot more information out there.  Just search on keywords like "3g tethering router".

Hope this helps.